# How to import AlpineJS with NPM?

Tags: npm, gruntjs, alpine.js

How is one supposed to import AlpineJS with NPM?

The AlpineJS docs say:

> From npm: Install the package from npm.
>
> `npm i alpinejs`
>
> Include it in your script.
>
> `import 'alpinejs'`

I put that last line into one of my JavaScript files. Nothing happened though. I figured, maybe I need a bundler like Grunt to make that import actually do something. I wouldn't know how the client should otherwise know that 'alpinejs' refers to `alpine.js` in `node_modules/alpinejes/dist`. Grunt just lets the line stand as it is and doesn't the AlpineJS file to my output directory.

What I want to achieve:

- Use AlpineJS in the client, without being dependent on the CDN
- Possibly: concatenating `alpine.js` with other script files to reduce the number of server requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a bundler that supports npm modules/imports to process your JS file (that includes the Alpine.js import). Webpack, rollup or parcel should all do the job.

Otherwise yes, you could concatenate the Alpine.js file at `node_modules/alpinejs/dist/alpine.js` with your JS file and use that (at which point you don't need the import statement)

Answer (score 3):

**Option one**

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
window.Alpine = Alpine
Alpine.start();
```

**Best option for me**

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
window.Alpine = Alpine;
queueMicrotask(() => {
    Alpine.start()
});
```

Comment: Alpine has a section about it : https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/installation

Comment: @Atem18  its not working for me

Comment: @RoshanJha It should. Post your configuration.

Comment: It doesn't say where though, which file? What is 'bundle?' Did you put this in layout for example?